# How do you execute the PaymentDetails request using the transactionId?

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How do you execute the `PaymentDetails` request using the `transactionId`?

I tried using the PaymentDetails.java code under the samples directory from [this](https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-java) code repository. I substituted in all the API credentials for my sandbox account, used the default `appId` for sandbox accounts (APP-80W284485P519543T) and used a `transactionId` of a transaction in my account.

The only results I can get returned are an internal_error.

I also get the same results when I execute a curl statement that is located at the bottom of the PaymentDetails [developer page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation).  Again I substitute in all of my sandbox API credentials, the default appId for sandbox and an existing transactionId.  The return again is an internal_error.

Is there more configuration I need on my sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample request and response that is working just fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PaymentDetailsRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <transactionId xmlns="">1BM714721N413291D</transactionId>
</PaymentDetailsRequest>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <responseEnvelope>
    <timestamp>2014-05-22T06:24:05.953-07:00</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <correlationId>ff6d39a2bc294</correlationId>
    <build>10902368</build>
  </responseEnvelope>
  <cancelUrl>http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Cancel.php</cancelUrl>
  <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
  <paymentInfoList>
    <paymentInfo>
      <transactionId>65A0503076751280F</transactionId>
      <transactionStatus>COMPLETED</transactionStatus>
      <receiver>
        <amount>10.00</amount>
        <email>sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com</email>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <paymentType>SERVICE</paymentType>
        <accountId>E7BTGVXBFSUAU</accountId>
      </receiver>
      <refundedAmount>0.00</refundedAmount>
      <pendingRefund>false</pendingRefund>
      <senderTransactionId>1BM714721N413291D</senderTransactionId>
      <senderTransactionStatus>COMPLETED</senderTransactionStatus>
    </paymentInfo>
    <paymentInfo>
      <receiver>
        <amount>5.00</amount>
        <email>usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com</email>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <invoiceId>123-ABCDEF</invoiceId>
        <paymentType>SERVICE</paymentType>
        <accountId>C9TAVNJFATXCS</accountId>
      </receiver>
      <refundedAmount>0.00</refundedAmount>
      <pendingRefund>false</pendingRefund>
    </paymentInfo>
  </paymentInfoList>
  <returnUrl>http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Return.php</returnUrl>
  <senderEmail>drew@angelleye.com</senderEmail>
  <status>INCOMPLETE</status>
  <payKey>AP-84R2524843917081W</payKey>
  <actionType>PAY</actionType>
  <feesPayer>EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
  <reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError>false</reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError>
  <sender>
    <email>drew@angelleye.com</email>
    <accountId>YW66KXBKJRRES</accountId>
    <useCredentials>false</useCredentials>
  </sender>
</ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse>
```

If you can post a sample of the full, raw request that you're sending to PayPal I may be able to help you find the problem.

Comment: The curl statement I executed is as follows:                       curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: my_sandbox_api_username"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: my_sandbox_api_password"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: my_sandbox_api_signature"
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T"
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails  -d
"transactionId=95W1454568676024G&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US"